# Llevo estudiando "XYZ" vs. He estado estudiando "XYZ" vs. Estoy estudiando "XYZ"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

What are the differences for:

1. Llevo estudiando "XYZ"
2. He estado estudiando "XYZ"
3. Estoy estudiando "XYZ"

If I want to say "I have been studying a lot of AI topics for my research," can I say "Estoy estudiando mucha inteligencia artificial para mi investigación"? Would this mean I just start studying and I will continue doing so? Or would it mean I've been studying for a while?

Comment: Option 3 just means you are currently doing it, with no implication of past history or future intent.

Comment: To add to @VladimirNu correct answer that BTW does not address your 3rd question I'd like to add that depending on what you want to say you could use "mucha" o "mucho". "Estoy estudiando mucha IA" = (I'm studying lots of AI) or "Estoy estudiando mucho IA" = (I'm studying a lot about AI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is incomplete, you need to specify *for how long*:

> Llevo estudiando español *tres meses*. = I've been studying spanish *for three months*.
>
> Llevo *tres meses* estudiando español. = *For the last three months* I've been studying spanish.
>
> Llevo estudiando *mucho tiempo*. = I've been studying *for so/too long*
>
> *Llevo tres días* estudiando para mi examen final. = *For the last 3 days* I've been studying for my exam.
>
> He estado estudiando para mi examen los últimos 3 días.

The meaning of this would be:

> I have been studying for my exam for the last three days.

---

On the other hand you can omit the *when* and say like this:

> He estado estudiando para mi examen, por eso no he tenido tiempo de llamarte.
>
> He estado estudiando español durante mucho tiempo.
>
> I have been studying for my exam, that's why I haven't call you.
>
> I have been studying spanish for a long time.

---

And then you have this:

> Estuve estudiando todo el fin de semana.
>
> I was studying the whole weekend.

Does it make it more clear?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you for your explanation. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad to help